# get numeric IDs of list of public Facebook pages from page name

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

I have a list of public Facebook pages (e.g. media outlets) of which I need the page ids (numeric) but only have the name. Since I have a lot of pages, I can't find all of them manually, so how would I process that manually?

As an example, my pages are:
`pages = ['financialtimes', 'dailytelegraph', 'theguardian']`
And I think I need to do something like this:

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/" + 'financialtimes' + '/?access_token=' + 'my_app_id' + 'my_app_secret'
print(url)
```

except I need that for a lot of pages. How do I do this?

Comment: [`?ids=financialtimes,dailytelegraph,theguardian`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=%3Fids%3Dfinancialtimes%2Cdailytelegraph%2Ctheguardian&version=v2.12) You can list up to 50 in one request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set up a function and pass the items of your list to that function, e.g.

```
# FB access
app_id = "my_app_id"
app_secret = "my_app_secret"
access_token = app_id + "|" + app_secret
#define function
def FacebookIDs(page_name, access_token=access_token):
    """ get page's numeric information """  
    # construct the URL string
    base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4"
    node = "/" + str(page_name)
    parameters = "/?access_token=%s" % access_token
    url = base + node + parameters
    # retrieve data    
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode()) 
    print(data)
    #return data # if you want the data not to be printed but to be the input for another function etc.
# define list
pages = ['financialtimes', 'dailytelegraph', 'theguardian']
# iterate over list
for page in pages: FacebookIDs(page, access_token)
```